# How to record screen with the audio coming from your Mac?

Tags: macos, audio, video, screen-recording

I'm trying to record my screen and the audio **only** coming from my Mac.

When I do a screen recording with quicktime, with audio settings: internal microphone, it records the video but with a lot of external noise (like cats).

How do I make sure that the audio of what is being played on the screen (like music being played on my Mac) is recorded in the video file?

I don't care if I'll have to record the screen and audio separately, or plug in earphones etc, I'd like to have a simple answer.

I have already tried the suggestions in these other questions:

- [How to record both screen and sound with Quicktime?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212829/how-to-record-both-screen-and-sound-with-quicktime-on-el-capitan)
- [How to record the sound also in a screen recording if the headphones are connected?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231427/how-to-record-the-sound-also-in-a-screen-recording-if-the-headphones-are-connect)
- [QuickTime Screen + Audio Capture](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60085/quicktime-screen-audio-capture)

Sadly their solutions don't work for me, as my recordings still capture external noises on macOS Catalina.

What software or setup can do this?

Comment: Hi Sara, you'll see we've reopened your question. It'd be fantastic if you could [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/371683/edit) it to include the version of macOS you're running on your Mac, as this will most likely play a factor on what is the best answer for you.

Answer (score 56):

Try using [Background Music](https://github.com/kyleneideck/BackgroundMusic#download).

When recording with Quicktime click the arrow and change the microphone to Background Music.

> You can record system audio with **Background Music**. With
> **Background Music** running, launch **QuickTime Player** and select **File > New Audio Recording** (or **New Screen Recording**, **New Movie Recording**). Then click the dropdown menu (`⌄`) next to the
> record button and select **Background Music** as the input device.
>
> You can record system audio and a microphone together by creating an
> [aggregate device](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202000) that
> combines your input device (usually Built-in Input) with the
> **Background Music** device. You can create the aggregate device using the **Audio MIDI Setup** utility under
> ***/Applications/Utilities***.

**Edit**: If you have homebrew installed you can install using `brew install --cask background-music`

<sup>[source](https://github.com/kyleneideck/BackgroundMusic/blob/master/README.md)</sup>

Comment: Your answer saved me, I've been struggling with BlackHole and BackgroundMusic works like a charm. Btw. from brew: `brew cask install background-music`

Comment: Why is it so huge? 224.5MB

Comment: I used `brew install cask background-music`

Comment: Now it's `brew install --cask background-music`

Answer (score 1):

Just came to post a solution that worked for me. (Caution) It does require a paid subscription though.

I tried Loom (the screen recording software) & their macOS app has a setting to enable system audio. Turn that on.

Then, make sure your microphone is set to None & then record!

The only negative really is that you have to pay to use it for any reasonable amount of time... But hey it worked for me & personally for me this whole situation is such a headache that it's worth it for the saved time & headache. Not a sponsor or anything, just wanted to share my own personal found solution.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with macOS Ventura, it's now possible for apps to capture system audio *without* installing any kernel extensions or audio server plug-ins.
[This app (Claquette)](https://apps.apple.com/app/apple-store/id587748131?pt=142877&ct=landing&mt=12) can be downloaded from the Mac App Store and it is able to record your screen with mic audio *and* system audio out of the box.
They also have a blog post on how system audio recording works on Ventura: https://peakstep.com/news/2023/06/claquette-system-audio-recording.html

Comment: This requires purchase to save recordings without watermark

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer; @Roxiun's answer really helped me, these are some tips I learned that also helped

First, follow @Roxiun's answer and install Background Music. Then..

#### Familiarise yourself with the tools

If, like me, you have several possible audio inputs and outputs, it can be a little confusing, but the three things to tinker with are:

1. An application on your mac called 'Audio MIDI Setup'
2. Background Music application (note that to access its options, click on the little circles icon in the mac menu bar (i.e. top of your mac screen)
3. After starting a new screen recording using Quicktime, there's a little menu will pop up on screen, which has an 'Options' section

#### Other quick tips

These are really convenient shortcuts to remember:

- To start a screen recording: <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>
- To end a screen recording: <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>escape</kbd>
- If you can see Background Music is using the microphone and want to close it, first look in the menu bar (top of screen). I couldn't spot it there, nor via Activity Monitor, so I used `killall Background\ Music` and that stopped it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Third-party Apps like OBS (Open Broadcaster Software)

> 1. Install OBS from [Here](https://obsproject.com/)
> 2. Set Up Audio Sources
> 3. Adjust Audio Settings
> 4. Start Recording
> 5. Stop Recording
> 6. Save Your Recording

There are many third-party screen recorders available, such as screenFlow, and Apowersoft Screen Recorder. Here you can read more about [How to Screen Record on Mac/MacBook Air/iMac with Audio](https://www.easeus.com/computer-instruction/screen-record-mac.html) which shows the best ways to record screens on a MacBook with internal audio and microphone sound.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).